# Undefined offset when writing to a file

Tags: php

I am attempting to write to a file using PHP. I am writing data from arrays.

Here's my code:

```
    $subject = $_SESSION['subject'];
    $section = $_SESSION['section'];
    $exam1 = $_SESSION['exam1'];
    $exam2 = $_SESSION['exam2'];
    $finalexam = $_SESSION['finalexam'];
    $average = $_SESSION['average'];

    $studentArray = $_SESSION['stringArray'];

    $file = $subject . "-" . $section . ".txt";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'a');
    $size = sizeof($studentArray);
    for($i = 0; $i<$size; $i++){
        fwrite($fh, $studentArray[$i] . " " . $exam1[$i] . " " . $exam2[$i] . " " .       $finalexam[$i] . " " . $average[$i] . " ");
}
```

I always get this notice when I try to access this page:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\CS120\MP\Grades.php on line 26
```

Line 26 is the one with the fwrite in the for-loop.
There's always a notice but the code writes to the file correctly.
Is there anything that can be done to remove/solve the notice/error?

Comment: well, obviously one of those arrays you're using in the fwrite don't have a #5 element, meaning that they're a different size than your $studentArray.

Comment: One of your arrays don't have an element of index `5`, i.e. the arrays have only 5 or less elements. It would be surprising if the resulting file is still correct.

Comment: Thanks all. I get it now. I'll try to do something :D

Comment: You should switch to multi-dimensional arrays so that you have all information together grouped for example by student. That would also reduce the chances of mismatches like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

Method 1

```
array_key_exists('1',$studentArray); // check whether array position 1 exist in array $studentArray
```

Method 2

```
if (isset($studentArray1])){
  // check whether array position 1 exist in array $studentArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the arrays does not have index at `5`. I would suggest using `isset()` before using it.

for example for your sessions i would do:

```
$subject = isset($_SESSION['subject']) ? $_SESSION['subject'] : '';
```

samething for your array. You need to check the index of array before using it.

Comment: Ahhh! I get it now. Thank you! I'll try to do something.